# How many distinct quadrilaterals can you draw inside a square of side length $4$?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

From the Iranian Geometry Olympiad, 2017:

> Each side of square $ABCD$ with side length of $4$ is divided into equal parts by three points.
> Choose one of the three points from each side, and connect the points consecutively to obtain
> a quadrilateral. Which numbers can be the area of this quadrilateral? [Here's a construction](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/wmascdz7).

[image]

I am interested in finding out:

1. How many quadrilaterals of distinct dimensions can you draw?
2. How many quadrilaterals of distinct areas can you draw?

A naïve approach is to multiply the number of possible vertices on each side of the square
($3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$). But that would overcount the number of *distinct* quadrilaterals (since you could obtain one by rotating or reflecting the other).

Of course, in the original problem, a brute-force approach would have sufficed. I would like to find the solution for a general case: given a square of $n + 1$ side length, how many distinct quadrilaterals are possible?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)?

Comment: @Luke Collins Unfortunately, no: only high school combinatorics.

Comment: Just "by rotating"? Or by reflecting too?

Comment: @IshanJMukherjee - Just because you're in high school does not mean you cannot handle Burnside's Lemma!  Esp. if you're in the small subset of highschoolers who do Olympiad problems.  Read the example in wikipedia and also search for some simple examples at MSE.  It's very neat and can answer your first question.